# Objective C Delegate - Find name of parent Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am in the middle of writing 10 separate utility classes for populating lookup tables from a server, one utility class for each lookup table.

I have noticed that all 10 are very similar, and I believe that I could make one abstract class that does 90% of the work and I could pass parameters into it when I instantiate it from the subclass.

The problem is that when the superclass wants to raise a delegate event it will have the same name regardless which subclass it is inherited in and so whatever class or controller owns the subclass will need a way of identifying which subclass the superclass is firing the delegate from.

Is there any way of telling what subclass owns the superclass that the delegate is being fired from?

e.g.
I have a superclass called 'Animal' that has a delegate event  'Animal wants food'
The subclasses 'dog' and 'cat' both inherit from 'Animal'
An NSObject called 'farmyard' instantiates both the 'dog' and 'cat' class and makes itself the delegate for both 'dog' and 'cat'.
When the instance of 'Animal' that is inherited by 'dog' fires the 'Animal wants food' this will be received by the 'farmyard' object. 
 - How does 'farmyard' know if it was 'dog' or 'cat' that fired the 'Animal wants food' delegate event?

Comment: But how? Inside farmyard I need to know so that I can respond correctly. Inside the event I need to either feed dog or cat and I need to know which one is was to be able to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the delegate method should pass the object as a parameter:

```
- (void)animalWantsFood:(Animal *)animal
```

Then the receiver can check the `animal`.

Look at the delegate methods provided throughout Apple code and you will see the same implementation of the delegate pattern.

Comment: just to make sure I understand your answer: so in this example I could check the animal object and I would be able to see if it was of type 'dog' or 'cat'?

Comment: Yes, you can check the class (`isKindOfClass:`), or use `isEqual:` / `containsObject:` if the delegate owns the original object.

Comment: Super duper. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what you describe is wrong -- which is why your question arises

an animal being a dog will always be of class dog

see: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Comment: The problem with your answer is that animal would not inherit from dog, dog would inherit from animal as dog is an animal but animal is not necessarily a dog. If you erase the superclass the name of the delegate event is still the same for both cat and dog and the issue of knowing which subclass raised the event remains

Comment: the superclass is Animal and the subclasses Dog and Cat -- my answer is ok

Comment: self is ALWAYS Dog or Cat and never animal

Comment: but we are not questioning 'self' we are questioning 'farmyard', how does 'farmyard' know that even 'Animal needs feeding' has come from 'dog.AnimalNeedsFeeding' or 'cat.AnimalNeedsFeeding'?

Comment: I don't get you.. you need to pass something ;)

Comment: you need the caller of a method? Pass it